# Why is my Raised Zombie glowing green?

Tags: path-of-exile

I love my raised zombies, but I'm getting worried for their health.  Recently, one of them started glowing green for no apparent reason.  It wasn't especially damaged, nor under any special effect (poison, ice, fire, ...).  The effect lasted until it got killed.

[image: raised zombie glowing green]

Answer (score 1):

Zombies randomly come in a couple colors: either reddish or cyan-ish (which is what you're calling green). It's just for variety, since any stats are changed.

Comment: By the way, during the closed beta we saw some color glitches with minions that happened when different effects were combined (the more famous affected spectres). If you see strange things just report them.

Comment: And is it normal that the cyan-ish color occurs way less often than the reddish one ?